# Styled Components & Typescript type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I've set up styled-components successfully in react-native, but I'm now using react-native-web and can't get styled-components to work on the web in this very simple example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default class View extends React.PureComponent {
  public render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Hey</h1>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const Container = styled.div;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Type error: JSX element type 'StyledComponentClass<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>, a...' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
Property 'render' is missing in type 'StyledComponentClass<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement>, HTMLHeadingElement>, a...'.  TS2605
> 11 |       <Container>
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
"target": "es6",
"jsx": "preserve",
"module": "esnext",
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "dist",
"types": [
  "react",
  "react-native",
  "jest"
],
"skipLibCheck": true,
"lib": [
  "es2015.promise",
  "esnext",
  "dom"
],
"alwaysStrict": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"strict": false,
"strictNullChecks": false,
"allowJs": true,
"esModuleInterop": false,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true
```

And my package.json:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.7.20",
  "@types/react-native": "^0.52.25",
  "typescript": "^2.9.2"
},
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  "styled-components": "^3.4.5",
}
```

I've tried to `rm -rf node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm install` to no avail.

Probably missing something simple here, but anyone have any ideas? Not sure what other information I can provide.

Comment: unfortunately react-native-web does not bring support for web APIs into react-native but rather allows react-native to be compiled to web APIs. That means you shouldn't be using divs or h elements or anything like that, so Josh's answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the React Native component instead of standard HTML tags.
Instead of `styled.div`, you'll use `styled.View`. Also you have to use react native's `Text` component in replace of standard HTML tags that would hold textual data such as `<H1>`.

So, this is what your code should translate to

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

export default class View extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                <Text>Hey</Text>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const Container = styled.View
```

Comment: D'oh! Always the obvious things that getcha. That's right, thanks